# Synchronous tasks run by Gulp does not run Properly (While setting AngularJs Environment)

Tags: angularjs, gulp, gulp-concat, gulp-uglify

I am learning Gulp. And I want to set up AngularJS Environment using Gulpand then minify and concat them .
But the problem is when I try to minify or concat the js file,then I think gulp did not find configFile.js that is created by "gulp-ng-config" for setting AngularJS Environment

Here is my gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var bower = require('gulp-bower');
var gulpNgConfig=require('gulp-ng-config');
var rimraf = require('rimraf');
var gp_concat = require('gulp-concat');
var gp_rename = require('gulp-rename');
var gp_uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
require('gulp-run-seq');


gulp.task('setLocalEnv', function () {
    console.log("gulp test running ");
    gulp.src('configFile.json')
        .pipe(gulpNgConfig('myApp.config', {
            environment: 'local'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./js'),function(end){
            console.log("set env",end);
        })
});

gulp.task('js-fef', function(){
    return gulp.src(['js/*','js/*/*'])
        .pipe(gp_concat('concat.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
        .pipe(gp_rename('uglify.js'))
        .pipe(gp_uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('clean', function (cb) {
    rimraf('./dist', cb);
});

gulp.task('bower', function() {
    return bower()
});
gulp.task('setProdEnv', function () {
    console.log("gulp test running ");
    gulp.src('configFile.json')
        .pipe(gulpNgConfig('myApp.config', {
            environment: 'production'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./js'))

});

gulp.task('default', [['clean','setLocalEnv','bower','js-fef']],function() {
    console.log("hello gulp");
});

gulp.task('production',['setProdEnv','bower'], function() {
    console.log("hello gulp");
});
```

This is the configFile.js that is created by "setLocalEnv" task

```
angular.module('myApp.config', [])
.constant('EnvironmentConfig', {"api":"http://localhost/"});
```

And this is the minify file generated

```
angular.module("app",[]),angular.module("app").controller("ctrl",["$scope",function(l){console.log("ctrl bind ")}]);
```

And here is the output of "gulp" default command

```
[20:09:56] Using gulpfile ~/WebstormProjects/NodeJs-Seed/public/gulpfile.js
[20:09:56] Starting 'clean'...
[20:09:56] Finished 'clean' after 2.46 ms
[20:09:56] Starting 'setLocalEnv'...
gulp test running 
[20:09:56] Finished 'setLocalEnv' after 20 ms
[20:09:56] Starting 'bower'...
[20:09:56] Using cwd:  /home/abhay/WebstormProjects/NodeJs-Seed/public
[20:09:56] Using bower dir:  lib
[20:09:56] Finished 'bower' after 3.85 ms
[20:09:56] Starting 'js-fef'...
[20:09:56] Finished 'js-fef' after 10 ms
[20:09:56] Starting 'default'...
hello gulp
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue by using

"gulp.run('js-fef')"

Now my gulp task looks like

```
gulp.task('setLocalEnv', function () {
    console.log("gulp test running ");
    gulp.src('configFile.json')
        .pipe(gulpNgConfig('myApp.config', {
            environment: 'local'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./js'),function(end){
            console.log("set env",end);
        })
        .on('end', function () {
            gulp.run('js-fef')
        });
});
```